# Why $ is a String and not Identifier in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This line of codes get error**

```js
listRef.current.style.transform = 'translateX(${230 + distance}px)'
```

```js
    import { ArrowBackIosOutlined, ArrowForwardIosOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
    import React, { useRef } from 'react'
    import "./list.scss";
    import ListItem from "../listItem/ListItem";
    
    export default function List() {
    
      const listRef = useRef()
    
      const handleClick = (direction) => {
        let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50
        if(direction === "left"){
          listRef.current.style.transform = 'translateX(${230 + distance}px)'
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <div className='list'>
            <span className="listTitle">Continue to watch</span>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <ArrowBackIosOutlined className="sliderArrow left" onClick={()=>handleClick("left")}/>
                <div className="container" ref={listRef}>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                    <ListItem/>
                </div>
                <ArrowForwardIosOutlined className="sliderArrow right" onClick={()=>handleClick("right")}/>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: `${xxx}` works inside `\`\`` only ... not `''` or `""`

Answer (score 1):

Change you code from

```
 const handleClick = (direction) => {
    let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50
    if(direction === "left"){
      listRef.current.style.transform = 'translateX(${230 + distance}px)'
    }
  }
```

to

```
 const handleClick = (direction) => {
    let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50
    if(direction === "left"){
      listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${230 + distance}px)`
    }
  }
```

What you need is called **template literal** in js.

Type Template Literal:

Mac: Shift + ` on keyboard

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals